# How do I get my inOrder function to work for a binary search tree of strings?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to make my inOrder function work for my test file. My function is supposed to order a string of data in a binary search tree. I expected my code to do just that but so far an only got the code to print out the root. I tried changing my function parameters to match the string of data but I'm it gives me errors. I know the algorithm is simple but I just can't figure out what parts of code go where. The code I am showing is my only attempt that runs. The code below is my Test File

```cpp
#include <string>
#include "bst.h"
using namespace std;

string data[] = { "able", "baker", "charlie", "dog", "easy", "fox", "george" };
    int size = 7;
    binary_search_tree<string> bst1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        bst1.insert(data[i]);
        cout << bst1 << endl;
    }
    cout << "balanced? " << bst1.is_balanced() << endl << endl;


        bst1.inOrder(bst1.get_root());
```

This is my Template

```cpp
#include "bst.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
/**
    * Add the item to this binary search tree as long as it
    * is not already present.
    * Return false if item is already  in the tree.
    * Return true if item is actually added to the tree.
    */
template <class T>
bool binary_search_tree<T>::insert(const T &item) {
    root = new binary_tree_node<T>(item);

    if(root == NULL)
    {
        insert(item);
    }

    if(root->data() == item)
    {
        return false;
    }else
    {
        return true; 
    }
}

/**
    * return the depth of the tree if the tree is balanced.
    * Return -2 if not.
    */
template <class T>
int  binary_search_tree<T>::is_balanced() {
    return check_balanced(root);
}

template <class T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const binary_tree_node<T> *root) {
    if(root != NULL) {
        out << "[";
        out << root->left() << " ";
        out << root->data();
        out << " " << root->right();
        out << "]";
    }
    return out;
}



template <class T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const binary_search_tree<T> &tree) {
    out << tree.root;
    return out;
}


template<class T>
void binary_search_tree<T>::inOrder(binary_tree_node<T>* ptr)
{

if(ptr != NULL)

{

    inOrder(ptr->left());

    std::cout << ptr->data();

    //if(ptr->left() != NULL && ptr->right() != NULL)

    std::cout << " " ;

    inOrder(ptr->right());

}
```

This is my HEADER

```cpp
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

#include "bintree.h"
#include <iostream>
template <class T>
class binary_search_tree {

public:
    binary_search_tree() {
        root = NULL;
    }

    /**
     * Add the item to this binary search tree as long as it
     * is not already present.
     * Return false if item is already  in the tree.
     * Return true if item is actually added to the tree.
     */
    bool insert(const T& item);



    ~binary_search_tree();


    /**
     * return the depth of the tree if the tree is balanced.
     * Return -2 if not.
     */
    int is_balanced();

    template <class S>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const binary_search_tree<S>& tree);

    binary_tree_node<T>* get_root() { return root; }

    void inOrder(binary_tree_node<T>*);
    //void inOrder(const T& item);
    //void inOrder();

private:
    binary_tree_node<T>* root;
};


template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const binary_tree_node<T>* root);


#include "bst.template"


#endif // BST_H
```

This Is my node Template

```cpp
// FILE: bintree.template
// IMPLEMENTS: The binary_tree node class (see bintree.h for documentation). 
#include <cassert>    // Provides assert
#include <cstdlib>   // Provides NULL, std::size_t
#include <iomanip>    // Provides std::setw
#include <iostream>   // Provides std::cout


    template<class Process, class BTNode>
    void inorder(Process f, BTNode *node_ptr)
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        if (node_ptr != NULL) {
            inorder(f, node_ptr->left());
            f(node_ptr->data());
            inorder(f, node_ptr->right());
        }
    }

    template<class Process, class BTNode>
    void postorder(Process f, BTNode *node_ptr)
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        if (node_ptr != NULL) {
            postorder(f, node_ptr->left());
            postorder(f, node_ptr->right());
            f(node_ptr->data());
        }
    }

    template<class Process, class BTNode>
    void preorder(Process f, BTNode *node_ptr)
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        if (node_ptr != NULL) {
            f(node_ptr->data());
            preorder(f, node_ptr->left());
            preorder(f, node_ptr->right());
        }
    }

    template<class Item, class SizeType>
    void print(binary_tree_node <Item> *node_ptr, SizeType depth)
    // Library facilities used: iomanip, iostream, stdlib
    {
        if (node_ptr != NULL) {
            print(node_ptr->right(), depth + 1);
            std::cout << std::setw(4 * depth) << ""; // Indent 4*depth spaces.
            std::cout << node_ptr->data() << std::endl;
            print(node_ptr->left(), depth + 1);
        }
    }

    template<class Item>
    void tree_clear(binary_tree_node <Item> *&root_ptr)
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        binary_tree_node<Item> *child;
        if (root_ptr != NULL) {
            child = root_ptr->left();
            tree_clear(child);
            child = root_ptr->right();
            tree_clear(child);
            delete root_ptr;
            root_ptr = NULL;
        }
    }

    template<class Item>
    binary_tree_node <Item> *tree_copy(const binary_tree_node <Item> *root_ptr)
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        binary_tree_node<Item> *l_ptr;
        binary_tree_node<Item> *r_ptr;

        if (root_ptr == NULL)
            return NULL;
        else {
            l_ptr = tree_copy(root_ptr->left());
            r_ptr = tree_copy(root_ptr->right());
            return
                    new binary_tree_node<Item>(root_ptr->data(), l_ptr, r_ptr);
        }
    }

    template<class Item>
    size_t tree_size(const binary_tree_node <Item> *node_ptr)
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        if (node_ptr == NULL)
            return 0;
        else
            return
                    1 + tree_size(node_ptr->left()) + tree_size(node_ptr->right());
    }
```

This is my Node Header

```cpp
// FILE: bintree.h (part of the namespace main_savitch_10)
// PROVIDES: A template class for a node in a binary tree and functions for 
// manipulating binary trees. The template parameter is the type of data in
// each node.
// 
// TYPEDEF for the binary_tree_node<Item> template class:
//   Each node of the tree contains a piece of data and pointers to its
//   children. The type of the data (binary_tree_node<Item>::value_type) is
//   the Item type from the template parameter. The type may be any of the C++
//   built-in types (int, char, etc.), or a class with a default constructor,
//   and an assignment operator.
//
// CONSTRUCTOR for the binary_tree_node<Item> class:
//   binary_tree_node(
//       const item& init_data = Item( ),
//       binary_tree_node<Item>* init_left = NULL,
//       binary_tree_node<Item>* init_right = NULL
//   )
//     Postcondition: The new node has its data equal to init_data,
//     and it's child pointers equal to init_left and init_right.
//
// MEMBER FUNCTIONS for the binary_tree_node<Item> class:
//   const item& data( ) const      <----- const version
//   and
//   Item& data( )                  <----- non-const version
//     Postcondition: The return value is a reference to the data from
//     this binary_tree_node.
//
//   const binary_tree_node* left( ) const  <----- const version
//   and
//   binary_tree_node* left( )              <----- non-const version
//   and
//   const binary_tree_node* right( ) const <----- const version
//   and
//   binary_tree_node* right( )             <----- non-const version
//     Postcondition: The return value is a pointer to the left or right child
//     (which will be NULL if there is no child).
//
//   void set_data(const Item& new_data)
//     Postcondition: The binary_tree_node now contains the specified new data.
//
//   void set_left(binary_tree_node* new_link)
//   and
//   void set_right(binary_tree_node* new_link)
//     Postcondition: The binary_tree_node now contains the specified new link
//     to a child.
//
//   bool is_leaf( )
//     Postcondition: The return value is true if the node is a leaf;
//     otherwise the return value is false.
//
// NON-MEMBER FUNCTIONS to maniplulate binary tree nodes:
//   tempate <class Process, class BTNode>
//   void inorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr)
//     Precondition: node_ptr is a pointer to a node in a binary tree (or
//     node_ptr may be NULL to indicate the empty tree).
//     Postcondition: If node_ptr is non-NULL, then the function f has been
//     applied to the contents of *node_ptr and all of its descendants, using
//     an in-order traversal.
//     Note: BTNode may be a binary_tree_node or a const binary tree node.
//     Process is the type of a function f that may be called with a single
//     Item argument (using the Item type from the node).
//
//   tempate <class Process, class BTNode>
//   void postorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr)
//      Same as the in-order function, except with a post-order traversal.
//
//   tempate <class Process, class BTNode>
//   void preorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr)
//      Same as the in-order function, except with a pre-order traversal.
//
//   template <class Item, class SizeType>
//   void print(const binary_tree_node<Item>* node_ptr, SizeType depth)
//     Precondition: node_ptr is a pointer to a node in a binary tree (or
//     node_ptr may be NULL to indicate the empty tree). If the pointer is
//     not NULL, then depth is the depth of the node pointed to by node_ptr.
//     Postcondition: If node_ptr is non-NULL, then the contents of *node_ptr
//     and all its descendants have been written to cout with the << operator,
//     using a backward in-order traversal. Each node is indented four times
//     its depth.
//
//   template <class Item>
//   void tree_clear(binary_tree_node<Item>*& root_ptr)
//     Precondition: root_ptr is the root pointer of a binary tree (which may
//     be NULL for the empty tree).
//     Postcondition: All nodes at the root or below have been returned to the
//     heap, and root_ptr has been set to NULL.
//
//   template <class Item>
//   binary_tree_node<Item>* tree_copy(const binary_tree_node<Item>* root_ptr)
//     Precondition: root_ptr is the root pointer of a binary tree (which may
//     be NULL for the empty tree).
//     Postcondition: A copy of the binary tree has been made, and the return
//     value is a pointer to the root of this copy.
//
//   template <class Item>
//   size_t tree_size(const binary_tree_node<Item>* node_ptr)
//     Precondition: node_ptr is a pointer to a node in a binary tree (or
//     node_ptr may be NULL to indicate the empty tree).
//     Postcondition: The return value is the number of nodes in the tree.

#ifndef BINTREE_H
#define BINTREE_H
#include <cstdlib>  // Provides NULL and size_t


template <class Item>
class binary_tree_node
{
public:
    // TYPEDEF
    typedef Item value_type;
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    binary_tree_node(
        const Item& init_data = Item(),
        binary_tree_node* init_left = NULL,
        binary_tree_node* init_right = NULL
    )
    {
        data_field = init_data;
        left_field = init_left;
        right_field = init_right;
    }
    // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    Item& data() { return data_field; }
    binary_tree_node*& left() { return left_field; }
    binary_tree_node*& right() { return right_field; }
    void set_data(const Item& new_data) { data_field = new_data; }
    void set_left(binary_tree_node* new_left) { left_field = new_left; }
    void set_right(binary_tree_node* new_right) { right_field = new_right; }
    // CONST MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    const Item& data() const { return data_field; }
    const binary_tree_node* left() const { return left_field; }
    const binary_tree_node* right() const { return right_field; }
    bool is_leaf() const
    {
        return (left_field == NULL) && (right_field == NULL);
    }
private:
    Item data_field;
    binary_tree_node* left_field;
    binary_tree_node* right_field;
};

// NON-MEMBER FUNCTIONS for the binary_tree_node<Item>:
template <class Process, class BTNode>
void inorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr);

template <class Process, class BTNode>
void preorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr);

template <class Process, class BTNode>
void postorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr);

template <class Item, class SizeType>
void print(binary_tree_node<Item>* node_ptr, SizeType depth);

template <class Item>
void tree_clear(binary_tree_node<Item>*& root_ptr);

template <class Item>
binary_tree_node<Item>* tree_copy(const binary_tree_node<Item>* root_ptr);

template <class Item>
std::size_t tree_size(const binary_tree_node<Item>* node_ptr);


#include "bintree.template"

#endif // BINTREE_H
```

From what it seems I am not getting the right variable inside my inOrder in main. I know I am following the right algorithm but I am not sure what to put for the desired result which is the sorted strings of data[] array. my code so far only prints george which is the root, but doesn't print the whole list.

Comment: Please atleast sort out where the problem may be. Have you tried using a debugger? Or have you tried printing the state of the bst at every stage?

Comment: I know that up to using the breakpoint I set on this line 'bst1.inOrder(bst1.get_root());' sets it to the root or last item entered with array data[]. I think I'm putting in the wrong variable or I am not having the right logic in my function inOrder.

Comment: `root = new binary_tree_node<T>(item); if(root == NULL) ...` The condition is never true - you've just assigned a non-NULL pointer to `root`. Your `insert` never results in a tree with more than one node - it just leaks the previously inserted node and sets the new one as the root. Notice how you never ever set the node's `left` or `right` pointers.